# Can checkins be blocked in VS2015 between certain times

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 can a check in be blocked between certain times of the day so they do not actually get checked in until after the time period expires?

Comment: Which VCS are you using?

Comment: Are you using [tag:TFVC] or [tag:Git]? Neither have this option out-of-the-box in TFS/VSTS.

Comment: I am using VS Professional 2015 along with TFVC

Answer (score 0):

For TFVC the only way I can think of doing this is to use scheduled tasks to change permissions.

[`tf permission`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) from the command line – thus can be scheduled – can be used to change permissions.